# Is there any way to remove specific formatting in Quill?

Tags: javascript, quill, react-quill

Given `Quill 1.3.6` and custom formatter in it, is there any way to programmatically remove all custom formatting from the whole editor? In another word is there any way to remove for example `bold` formatting from every place it occurs in the document?

`quill.removeFormat()` seems not the option since it doesn't give you a filter by format.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass `false` as the value argument to the `format` functions, you can remove a specific type of formatting.

E.g. `format('bold', false)` to remove bold from currently selected text (but no other formatting). Or `formatText(0, 100, 'bold', false)` to remove bold formatting for the first 100 characters.

This is specified in the API documentation (though it only appears for `formatLine` and `formatText`, it works for format too): https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formatting

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar thing with the npm package sanitize-html.

An exemple for your use case :

```
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';
const dirtyText = '<p>My <strong>dirty</strong> text</p>';
const cleanText = sanitizeHtml(dirtyText, {
  exclusiveFilter: (frame) => frame.tag !== 'strong'
});
```

otherwise, you can (I think it's better) list the tags you allow with the "allowedTags" property :

```
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';
const dirtyText = '<p>My <strong>dirty</strong> text</p>';
const cleanText = sanitizeHtml(dirtyText, {
  allowedTags: ['span', 'p', 'h2', 'a', 'u', 'em', 's']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with such solution (which seems doesn't have great performance, but doing what I need).

```
const deltas = quill.getContents().map(delta => {
    const attributes = delta.attributes;
    if (attributes) {
        delete attributes['<YOUR ATTRIBUTE TO DELETE>'];
    }

    return delta;
});
quill.setContents(deltas);
```